# Does TDD mean I have to write a test for every method no matter how complicated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

Suppose I have a user class that has a method is_old_enough?

The method just checks that the age is over 18. Seems pretty simple.

Does TDD mean I have to write a test for this, even though it is trivial?

```
class User
  def is_old_enough?
    self.age >= 18
  end
end
```

And if so, why? What is the benefit of writing a test for this?  You'd just be testing that x >= y works the way you expect the >= operator to work.

Because the most likely scenario I see happening is the following:

It turns out the age should actually be 21.  That's a bug that the test didn't catch, because they had the wrong assumptions when we wrote the code. So then they go in and change the method to >= 21. But now the test fails! So they have to go and change the test too. So the test didn't help, and actually gave a false positive alarm when they were refactoring.

Looks like tests for simple methods like this are not actually testing anything useful, and are actually hurting you.

Comment: I think "test driven" means that you test your code. It doesn't mean you have to become stupid. On the other hand sometimes relatively easy code can have a bug. And if someone changes the definition in one place, the test might fail in another. You would have to have both a positive and negative test (e.g. "pass with 18, fail with 17"). If the limit is changed to 16, your second test will now fail. I always tell people "when you learn something new, don't unplug the common sense module to make space for the new information".

Comment: With TDD, you don't write a test for a method, you write a method(s) for a test.  You FIRST write a test that describes some desired but not yet implemented behavior.  Then you write the necessary code to make the test pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing test coverage and Test-Driven Development. TDD is just a practice of developing an automated test that is going to verify the use cases of some new feature. Usually it starts off failing because you've stubbed the functionality out or simply haven't implemented it. Next, you develop the feature until the test passes.

The idea is that you are in the mindset of developing tests that verify your important use cases/features. This doesn't necessarily mean you need to test simple functions if you think they are covered by your regular feature tests.

In terms of coverage, that's really up to you as the developer (or team) to decide. Obviously having around 1-to-1 coverage of tests to API is desired, but you have a choice as to whether you think it's always going to be easy enough to implement `is_old_enough?`. It may seem like an easy implementation now, but perhaps that will change in the future. You just need to be mindful of those kinds of decisions when you choose whether to write a test or not. More than likely, though, your use case won't change and the test is easy to write. It doesn't hurt to feel confident in all areas of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question has more to do with unit testing than TDD in particular.

**Short answer:** focus on behaviors

**Long answer:** Well, there is a nice phrase out there: BDD is TDD done right, and I completely agree. While BDD and TDD are is large part the "same" thing (not equal, mind you!), BDD for me gives the context for doing TDD. You can read a lot on the Internet around this, so I will not write essays here, but let me say this:

- In your example, yes, the test is necessary because the rule that
  user is old enough is a behavior of User entity. Test serves as a
  safety net for many other things yet to come which would rely on this
  piece of information, and test for me would document this behavior
  very well (I actually tend to read tests to find out what the developer had in mind when writing a class - you learn what to expect, how the class behaves, what are the edge cases etc.)
- I don't really see how the test would not catch the refactoring, since I would write the test with numbers 18, 19, 25 and 55 in mind (just a bunch of asserts typed very fast very easily)

Very important piece of the puzzle is that unit tests are just one technique that you need. If your design is lacking, you will find yourself writing too many meaningless tests, or you will have hell testing classes doing multiple things etc. You need to have very good SOLID skills to be able to shape out classes in a way that testing only their public interfaces (this includes protected methods as well) actually tests the entire class. As said before, focusing on behaviors is the key here.